# Servlet not found from a GWT web application

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, gwt

I am struggling since few days with a problem concerning my GWT application and the servlets called from the application.

I am actually coding a web app with Java and GWT for my research institute. The goal is to produce an XML file containing metadata from user inputs, after flight campaigns. Until then, I always coded my apps with Python or Matlab, and I started to use Java and GWT two months ago (to allow users to access those tools online).

The web app consists of a client side (the GUI) and a server side with servlets to allow the user to download the generated XML file, to print a pdf report, or to upload the XML file (to work on it again). Not really complex.

Using Eclipse 4.4 and the embedded Jetty server, no problem at all ! It's really nice, the XML file is well formated, the download and upload functions are ok.
Then I wanted to test it on my laptop with a Tomcat server (Apache Tomcat 7, for Ubuntu 14.04), I deployed the .war (which was successfully unzipped by Tomcat), and I managed to access the web app from firefox.
But when I try to access the servlets (to upload an xml file), the anwser returned is "HTTP ERROR 404. Problem accessing /upload. Reason: NOT_FOUND"
I tried to found a solution using google, and I found few posts on the same subject, but all posted solutions didn't work in my case ...

Here is the part of my main code to call the servlet:

```
final FileUpload myFileUpload = new FileUpload();
myFileUpload.setName("uploadFormElement");
myFileUpload.getElement().setId("uploadFormElement");
myFileUpload.getElement().setId("myFile");
panel.add(myFileUpload);
final FormPanel myUploadForm = new FormPanel();
myUploadForm.setAction("/upload");
myUploadForm.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
myUploadForm.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
```

Here is my servlet code:

```
package com.eufar.asmm.server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

@SuppressWarnings("hiding")
public class UploadFunction<FileItem> extends HttpServlet implements Servlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

    FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

    try {
        List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
        Iterator iter = items.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            Object obj = iter.next();
            if(obj == null) continue;
            org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem item = (org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem)obj;
            if(item.isFormField()){
                String name = item.getName();
                String value = "";
                if(name.compareTo("textBoxFormElement")==0){
                    value = item.getString();                       
                } 
                else {
                    value = item.getString();                       
                }
                response.getWriter().write(name + "=" + value + "\n");
             } 
             else {
                byte[] fileContents = item.get();
                String message = new String(fileContents);
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                response.setContentType("text/html");
                response.getWriter().write(message);                    
             }
        }          
    } catch (Exception ex) {            
        response.getWriter().write("ERROR:" + ex.getMessage());
    }
}   
}
```

And here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>DownloadFunction</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.eufar.asmm.server.DownloadFunction</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DownloadFunction</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>DownloadFunction</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>UploadFunction</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.eufar.asmm.server.UploadFunction</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadFunction</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/upload</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Asmm_eufar.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

For information, all seems to be ok in the WEB-INF directory with all classes, all needed libraries ...
I did a quick test with Eclipse : to generate the defaut GWT web app ("Enter your name") and deploy it on Tomcat. With Eclipse, no issue, but Tomcat can't find the default servlet ...

So, finally, I can't say if my code is absolutely ok (I am a beginner), and I can't say if the problem can a wrong Tomcat configuration (I am a researcher not server admin).

I hope you will be able to help me.

Kind regards,

Olivier

Edit: I probably forgot to add some details about how I added my app to Tomcat and how I launch it.

With Eclipse, I compile the code, then I move all files and directories included in the "war" directory to a directory called "MyApp" (an example). Then I compress this directory to a .zip file and changed ".zip" to ".war". This .war file is then copy/past to the "webapps" directory of Tomcat. Tomcat process the .war file and I obtain a directory calle "MyApp", in which I have another "MyApp" directory containing all my files. Finally, I launch Firefox and access my app with the following Url : http://localhost:8080/MyApp/MyApp/Myapp.html

With the proposals given by Thomas, I should access the Upload function with the Url http://localhost:8080/MyApp/MyApp/upload. But the returned error is: "State HTTP 404. MyApp/MyApp/upload The requested resource is not available (in french on my computer). It differs a bit from what I have with the code I posted above ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One likely difference is the webapp's *context path*. In dev, the web app is deployed at root (`contextPath=/`) whereas in Tomcat it's using the name of your war file by default (`contextPath=/mywebapp/`).

Your form always posts to `http://<server>:<port>/upload` but in Tomcat your servlet is at `http://<server>:<port>/mywebapp/upload`.

You'll want to use:

```
myUploadForm.setAction(GWT.getHostPageBaseUrl() + "/upload");
```

or possibly

```
myUploadForm.setAction("upload");
```

(without the leading slash)

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your answer. I tried both of your solutions, but no luck, 404 error. I tried also by modifing the web.xml file according to what you I proposed, but the result is the same ...

Comment: Can you please post the action URL of the form in the HTML page from the source view or even better DOM inspector in your browser? This will show the actual real address that is called, then we can compare your configuration.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you asked for ... I am real beginner here with web development and java ^^'. How can I see the action URL of the form in the HTML page ? If I take a look in the source view (firefox one), I only have the source of my application html file (with a link to the javascript code). I donwloader DOM Inspector, just in case, but I don't see (yet) how to use it ...

Comment: I put some comments in my original post to show how I put my app into Tomcat server and how I launch it. I can't do more for now as I am in vacation for few days ..

Comment: Your `WEB-INF` should be at the root of your WAR file; you seem to have everything within a `MyApp` folder inside the WAR. In other words, when you open the WAR (or ZIP, before renaming), you should see your `MyApp.html` file and `WEB-INF` folder right there, not a `MyApp` folder containing them. Because it's in a subfolder, your `WEB-INF/web.xml` is ignored by Tomcat.

Comment: I wasn't really clear with my explanation, I am sorry ... I have Myapp.html at the root of the war file, as well as the WEB-INF directory, which contains the web.xml and directories as "classes", "lib", etc ... that was the first thing I checked.

Comment: I understand now what you meant. Yes the structure of my app was: /webapps/MyApp/MyApp/ and all dependencies in the same directory. I corrected the war file to have the structure: /webapps/MyApp/. Tomcat refused to start the application. In the catalina.out file, I noticed that the cause of the problem is a wrong mapping with the DownloadFunction in the servlet mapping. You were absolutely right: my WEB-INF/web.xml was ignored before, because of the wrong structure of MyApp. I will correct it once at work and will report the result. I hope it was the problem (and a stupid one ...)

Comment: Hi Thomas. I just modified my web.xml file (<url-pattern>/upload</url-pattern> ... since my first post I changed it a lot of times ... so I reverted it to what I posted above), corrected my main app file with your proposal (myUploadForm.setAction(GWT. getHostPageBaseUrl() + "/upload")) and was careful about the structure of all my directories, to access the app with the URL http://localhost:8080/MyApp/Myapp.html. And it was a success ! Now I can upload and download an xml file ! I should have been careful about this structure problem ... Thanks for your patience and your help !